# AES 128 Bit IOS Encryption

Tags: ios, aes, rijndael

I am new to encryption in IOS. I've String and i want to encrypt it using AES-128 bit (rijndael algorithm) in IOS. I have found many links but did not get the exact answer.What is the best way to do that

Comment: CRDave : I'va alredy checked that link, but did not find the solution for my problem.

Comment: Answer of that question give link to post which has zip file to download and that zip file contain full project of AES. What else you need?? That some one come and type hole code in your project?

Comment: @Piyushmatta Unfortunatly using encryption in a manner to provide security is not an easy thing. [RNCryptor](RNCryptor) is a good solution that covers all the basic issues. If you want to encrypt the data in a file consider using `writeToFile:options:error:` with `NSDataWritingOptions`. If you want some sample code see this [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23641521/451475) but that requires data in and out as well as a full length key and iv.

Comment: Note: Rijndael is not the same as AES, it has more options such as additional block sizes. It is best to stick with AES (block size 128). Do not confuse block size with key length.

Comment: The link in the duplicate is terrible in that it relies on a link in one of the answers that links to project code.

Comment: @Thanks for your answer Zaph.  Actually i have to use Rijndael algorithm  to encrypt a string ,because the web app of my mobile app is using the same and i have to consume that service, i  have key and iv (provided by web team ) but not solution ti implement it on IOS.