# Implement jcryption in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, rijndael, jcryption

I need to implement `jcryption` in IOS. I have gone through the library it uses **Rijndael encryption** internally to encrypt the data.

I have tried `AES256EncryptWithKey` but it is not giving me expected encryption key.

Any help on this would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rijndael with a 128-bit block size is AES. Use Common Crypto on iOS, it uses the hardware encryption engine. There are several ObjC AES answers here on SO, see [iOS AES Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23641521/451475).

For a detailed answer you will need to provide your usage information on jCryption.

Also notice that jCryption has been discontinued. If you are trying to use jCryption in place of HTTPS the correct solution is to use HTTPS, see [jCryption](http://www.jcryption.org).